# Convert from World to Device coordinates

Tags: graphics, linear-algebra, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation

Using illustrations, explain how a point P(3,7,11) can be converted from world coordinates to device coordinates.
I don't quite get the matrices involved in the whole process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awesome. I'm going to change the point slightly and explain the concept in 2D instead of 3D that might help you understand.

Games are the easiest real world application for me to explain so lets do this!

This level of a game below is our WORLD.

[image]

This black box in this picture is our DEVICE.

[image]

The red dot in both pictures is the point. So in World coordinates lets guestimate that the red dot has values of (100,100).

In device coordinates the points has values of probably (30, 80).

The transformation that will get you from World to Device coordinates is

```
1 0 70
0 1 20
0 0 1
```

I won't go into depth about which pieces of the matrixes do what, you should be able to reference any text book or linear transformation article and find out how to do scale, rotate, translate. I'm just trying to show the concept in action.

Now when you put all those magical things together in the real world your 3D games will have WORLD coordinates, Screen coordinates (in 2D), Object Coordinantes, ect... and converting in between is critical for collision detection, user interaction, events, ect...

Let me know if this helped.

Comment: @Kimberly H. Was this able to help you?

Comment: @KimberleyH. Please upvote and or accept if my answer was able to help.